# odd (?) spacing for logic notation

Tags: math-mode, spacing, math-operators

I write code:

```
$\sim(p\land q)\iff (\sim p\lor \sim q)$
```

and my output is like this:

[image: siple logic law with werid spacing between letter and logic symbol]

As you can see, the `\land` symbol is nice in between 'p' and 'q', but the `\lor` symbol stick somehow to the left, to the 'p' without space.
I could manually "fix" it with forcefully added space, but I don't understand why the left and right side would have different output. Why in one example it stick to letter before, in second not. Am I doing something wrong? Is there better way to fix it without adding `\;` in math mode?

Comment: `\sim` is set up as a binary relation (like =) and you are using it as a prefix negation so you want to define a command that is equivalent to `\mathord{\sim}` (or equivalently just `{\sim}` (or perhaps \mathop)

Comment: The negation symbol intended to go with `\lor` and `\land` is `\lnot`, though of course you could decide you don't like how it looks. I wonder if in that case it would not be more idiomatic to redefine `\lnot` to have the appearance of `\mathord{\sim}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\sim` is set up as an infix relation so has the spacing of `=` which affects the spacing of adjacent binary operators, you want a `\mathord` (like a letter) or perhaps better `\mathop` (like `\log`) symbol as you are using this as a prefix operator.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\sim(p\land q)\iff (\sim p\lor \sim q)$

${\sim}(p\land q)\iff ({\sim} p\lor {\sim} q)$

$\mathop{{}\sim}(p\land q)\iff (\mathop{{}\sim} p\lor \mathop{{}\sim} q)$

\end{document}
```